# replace only the first and only the last match using 'sed'

Tags: sed

I want to replace, and old string with a new one. This is what I used

```
sed -i "0,|$old|{s|$old|$new|g}" file
```

but it gives me error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unexpected `,'
```

How to change it?

Also

How to change only the last occurence?

example

```
Apple / Banana / Apple / orange / Apple
                                    |
                                    |
                                   \-/
Apple / Banana / Apple / orange / Melon
```

Comment: The later part of your question (about replacing the *last*  occurrence) is much different imho and should be asked as a separate question - and perhaps better asked on the *Unix &  Linux* site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the exception of the substitute (`s`) command, you need to preface an alternate delimiter with a backslash i.e. to use `|` as a regex delimiter in your range it has to be `0,\|$old|`

So

```
sed -i "0,\|$old|{s|$old|$new|g}" file
```

should work (although the brackets around the substitute expression are unnecessary, since it is a single expression).

Note that including the `g` (global) flag will cause sed to replace *all* instances of `$old` within the *first* matching line:

```
$ echo -e "old and bold\nolder and bolder\noldest and boldest" | sed "0,\|old| s|old|new|g"
new and bnew
older and bolder
oldest and boldest
```

If you want to replace the very first instance only, remove the `g` i.e.

```
$ echo -e "old and bold\nolder and bolder\noldest and boldest" | sed "0,\|old| s|old|new|"
new and bold
older and bolder
oldest and boldest
```

Comment: just remove it or remove |g?

Comment: I was going to mention the `g` but assumed that the OP knows what they want (i.e. to replace *all* instances of `$old` within the *first* matching line)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
sed -i "0,/${old}/s,${old},${new}," file
```